# How can a teacher give effective feedback to students?

Tags: teaching

I wish to know, in general, how can professors provide feedback to students which the students will actually listen to and will use to improve themselves? I think to some extent there is a variability on what type of feedback people are receptive too, so there should be some sort of way which covers a large number of cases.

Effective in sense they actually make a positive difference when students are tested in some way on their comprehension of the subject.

Comment: I think you need to be more specific.  In particular, I think you need to say exactly what is meant by "improve."  There is a whole field of research called "education" which studies how professors can help students improve for various kinds of improvement.

Comment: Also, I suspect "feedback" is not the solution if students are not improving; something needs to be done proactively.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following works if the scale is reasonable, though it is harder in very large classes unless you have a lot of help.

The main idea is to permit resubmission of already graded work for a grade improvement (though not full marks) if the work is actually improved.

The mechanism is to write comments directly on student papers along with a point total up to the maximum for that assignment. In this example, a paper is worth 100 and the student first gets 80 along with comments on why it is lacking.

The student is then permitted to resubmit an improved version for some fraction of the lost points, but not all. So, 95 might be possible in a resubmission, but not 100.

To make this easy (easier?) for the grader, all work is submitted in a folder and all prior work is also included with resubmissions. So, the grader can easily see what was lacking previously and can judge the changes. I also required (usually computer programs) that the changes to the original be highlighted with a marking pen (highlighter).

I used the above extensively and it helped students get over misconceptions. It also avoided needing to have office consultations and totally avoided grading complaints. I never saw a downside and processing a folder was very quick. But my scale was reasonable, usually less than 30 students.

I actually permitted more than one resubmission and a few students (not many) needed and benefitted from it. However, since the rework takes time away from current work, I'd occasionally (very) have to tell a student "one more chance" so that they could spend more time on the current tasks.

Another key idea is that the commenter should give minimal "hints" that permit (require) the student to do some actual work to improve the paper. Don't tell them how to fix it, but point out what the problem is an/or why it is a problem. In office hour visits the same should be true. For that, you can ask them why they made certain decisions and point out the (negative) consequences of poor decisions. Let them work out the solution so that it is a learning experience for them, not just following your instructions.

To do this in a larger group would require, I think, well trained TAs and regular meetings with them to set guidelines. The same person probably needs to handle the resubmissions for any given student for it to be scalable, though I never had to explore that.

---

My sense is that effectiveness of this derives from the fact that students have to actually engage with your feedback to win a few points. This is reinforcing. Some students need more reinforcement than others do.

Comment: This was in high school, but the best English/writing teacher I had did just this, and pretty much all of my classmates improved greatly in their writing skills during the course of her classes.